# What's the translation of a "through ticket" in French?

Tags: traduction, transports

A through ticket [is](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/through-ticket#:%7E:text=a%20ticket%20that%20you%20can,or%20planes%20on%20the%20way):

> a ticket that you can use to travel to a place, even though you may change trains or planes on the way

What's the translation of a *through ticket* in French? Google Translate, DeepL and Linguee didn't help.

Comment: It looks like a concept invented to solve multi-operator market problems, which we don't have a lot of in European French-speaking countries - so far :) All I can think of is a plane ticket with stopover involving 2 airlines from the same alliance, but in that case we tend to see the negative side of things: "avec escale", "avec changement".

Answer (score 2):

On trouve aussi quand le nom ou quand *trough-ticketing* vient modifier *system/service* : « transport avec billet de correspondance » ([Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=THROUGH-TICKETING&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)).

Answer (score 1):

Several sources would use *billet direct* in French to convey the meaning of the *through ticket*. Sometimes the term *billet direct combiné* is also used to signify interline change (source: [TERMIUM Plus, The Government of Canada’s terminology and linguistic data bank](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=&index=alt&srchtxt=BILLET%20DIRECT%20COMBINE)).

References:

1. [2021/C 68/ 01. Position (EU) No 1/2021 of the Council at first reading with a view to the adoption of a Regulation of the European Parliament and of the Council on rail passengers' rights and obligations.](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=OJ:C:2021:068:FULL&from=EN) in *Official Journal of the European Union*, C 68.

> (9) ‘through-ticket’ means a through-ticket as defined in point (35) of Article 3 of Directive 2012/34/EU;

with [the French version of the same document](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/FR/TXT/PDF/?uri=OJ:C:2021:068:FULL&from=FR):

> 9. «billet direct»: un billet direct au sens de l’article 3, point 35), de la directive 2012/34/UE;

2. Similarly, in the opinion (IMCO-AD-619085) on a similar question ([English](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/IMCO-AD-619085_EN.docx) / [French](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/IMCO-AD-619085_FR.docx)):

> ... This opinion therefore contains a clearer definition of through-ticket and a proposal to set up online programming interfaces (API's) through which railway undertakings shall provide non-discriminatory access to all travel information, including real time operational, timetable and tariffs data. In order to give passengers the possibility to make an informed decision when purchasing tickets through a duty for ticket vendors and railway undertakings to inform passengers when the price of a so-called through-ticket substantially varies from the accumulated prices paid when buying tickets separately from the different operators.

is written in French as follows:

> ... Le présent avis contient donc une définition plus claire du billet direct et une proposition concernant la mise en place d’interfaces de programmation en ligne (API) à travers lesquelles les entreprises ferroviaires devront fournir un accès non discriminatoire à toutes les informations relatives aux voyages, y compris, en temps réel, des données opérationnelles sur les tarifs et un calendrier. Pour que les voyageurs puissent acheter leurs billets en toute connaissance de cause, les entreprises de vente de billets et les compagnies ferroviaires doivent avoir l’obligation d’informer les passagers lorsque le prix d’un billet direct diffère considérablement de la somme des prix payés en cas d’achat séparé des billets qui le composent auprès des différents opérateurs.

Therefore, at least in the European Union, the term *billet direct* is used quite often in the legal sense.

Links to the English version of the documents were obtained via [Lawinsider page on *through ticket*](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/through-ticket), and French ones by minor manual editing of the hyperlinks.

Comment: Thanks, "billet direct" is quite misleading as it typically means non-stop.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt also added a version from Canadian Government: _billet direct combiné_. I don't think that in French it is as "non-stop" of a connotation as in English.

Comment: Thanks, "billet direct combiné" sounds better (not/less misleading).

Comment: A "billet combiné" is more used to describe something that covers 2 activities, like 2 museums, or multi-modal transport (plane and then bus for instance) than multi-line, single transport mode tickets. "Billet direct combiné" makes sense but is definitely not idiomatic in Europe.